# Android Json tag into String

Tags: android, json

I use this code for reading a tag by a specific URL:

```
public static String ter(final String PRIVATE) {
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("my url string"));
        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
        String event = (String) jsonObject.get("EVENT");
        return event;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return PRIVATE;
}
```

Then I set my subTitle with PRIVATE in this way:

```
getActionBar().setSubtitle("test"+ter(PRIVATE));
```

But when I run my app, in subTitle I read only text "test" with text "null" and it doesn't read the tag of JSON. Anyone has any idea? Is my code wrong?

Comment: Can you post your full JSON response?

Answer (score 0):

Because you may have not initializes your variable therefore it is pointing towards null values....

> When ever we create object,either by calling that method or by initializing variable at declaration, we can avoid null pointer exception...

Please refer to this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: I Mohit. I have create PRIVATE variable before. String PRIVATE = null and i would like to set a tag json into this value

Comment: If you performing this in your `Async Task` try to set your SubTitle in `onPostMethod`

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the subtitle to `PRIVATE`, but if your parsing succeeds, you're returning`event`. You're also sending `PRIVATE` into this function, for some reason.